# Trusted CA Certificate Issue in Jdeveloper Weblogic server

Tags: security, jsp, ssl-certificate, jdeveloper, weblogic11g

Everytime i run my Java project in Jdeveloper following WARNING appears due to hwcih my JSP page appears late.How do I avoid this

```
     <Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090171> <Loading the    identity       certificate and private key stored under the alias DemoIdentity from the jks keystore file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\DemoIdentity.jks.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090169> <Loading trusted certificates from the jks keystore file C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\DemoTrust.jks.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090169> <Loading trusted certificates from the jks keystore file C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_3\jre\lib\security\cacerts.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2,OU=(c) 2009 Entrust\, Inc. - for authorized use only,OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms,O=Entrust\, Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=thawte Primary Root CA - G3,OU=(c) 2008 thawte\, Inc. - For authorized use only,OU=Certification Services Division,O=thawte\, Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 3,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH,C=DE". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 2,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH,C=DE". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=GlobalSign,O=GlobalSign,OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "OU=Security Communication RootCA2,O=SECOM Trust Systems CO.\,LTD.,C=JP". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority,OU=(c) 2008 VeriSign\, Inc. - For authorized use only,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,O=VeriSign\, Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=KEYNECTIS ROOT CA,OU=ROOT,O=KEYNECTIS,C=FR". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G3,OU=(c) 2008 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=Entrust Root Certification Authority - G2,OU=(c) 2009 Entrust\, Inc. - for authorized use only,OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms,O=Entrust\, Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=thawte Primary Root CA - G3,OU=(c) 2008 thawte\, Inc. - For authorized use only,OU=Certification Services Division,O=thawte\, Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 3,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH,C=DE". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 2,OU=T-Systems Trust Center,O=T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH,C=DE". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=GlobalSign,O=GlobalSign,OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R3". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "OU=Security Communication RootCA2,O=SECOM Trust Systems CO.\,LTD.,C=JP". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=VeriSign Universal Root Certification Authority,OU=(c) 2008 VeriSign\, Inc. - For authorized use only,OU=VeriSign Trust Network,O=VeriSign\, Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=KEYNECTIS ROOT CA,OU=ROOT,O=KEYNECTIS,C=FR". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.> 
<Oct 31, 2012 2:44:02 PM IST> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090898> <Ignoring the trusted CA certificate "CN=GeoTrust Primary Certification Authority - G3,OU=(c) 2008 GeoTrust Inc. - For authorized use only,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US". The loading of the trusted certificate list raised a certificate parsing exception PKIX: Unsupported OID in the AlgorithmIdentifier object: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11.>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update Weblogic to a 10.3.3 or greater